# How are java interfaces implemented internally? (vtables?)

Tags: java, interface, internals, vtable, language-implementation

C++ has multiple inheritance. The implementation of multiple inheritance at the assembly level can be quite complicated, but there are good [descriptions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_table) online on how this is normally done (vtables, pointer fixups, thunks, etc).

Java doesn't have multiple implementation inheritance, but it does have multiple interface inheritance, so I don't think a straight forward implementation with a single vtable per class can implement that. How does java implement interfaces internally?

I realize that contrary to C++, Java is Jit compiled, so different pieces of code might be optimized differently, and different JVMs might do things differently. So, is there some general strategy that many JVMs follow on this, or does anyone know the implementation in a specific JVM?

Also JVMs often devirtualize and inline method calls in which case there are no vtables or equivalent involved at all, so it might not make sense to ask about actual assembly sequences that implement virtual/interface method calls, but I assume that most JVMs still keep some kind of general representation of classes around to use if they haven't been able to devirtualize everything. Is this assumption wrong? Does this representation look in any way like a C++ vtable? If so do interfaces have separate vtables and how are these linked with class vtables? If so can object instances have multiple vtable pointers (to class/interface vtables) like object instances in C++ can? Do references of a class type and an interface type to the same object always have the same binary value or can these differ like in C++ where they require pointer fixups?

(for reference: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262428/how-does-net-clr-implement-an-interface-internally) asks something similar about the CLR, and there appears to be a good explanation in [this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx#S12) though that may be outdated by now. I haven't been able to find anything similar for Java.)

**Edit:**

- I mean 'implements' in the sense of "How does the GCC compiler implement integer addition / function calls / etc", not in the sense of "Java class ArrayList implements the List interface".
- I am aware of how this works at the JVM bytecode level, what I want to know is what kind of code and datastructures are generated by the JVM after it is done loading the class files and compiling the bytecode.

Comment: You mention interface inheritance and implementation inheritance. Implementation inheritance is difficult as you need to have a defined search order. Interface inheritance is way simpler. You just have a map with all method signatures that need to be implemented. No search order required (as there is no implementation attached to it). There is no order there.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The key feature of the HotSpot JVM is [inline caching](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/PerformanceTechniques). 
This doesn't actually mean that the target method is inlined, but means that an assumption
is put into the JIT code that every future call to the virtual or interface method will target
the very same implementation (i.e. that the call site is monomorphic). In this case, a
check is compiled into the machine code whether the assumption actually holds (i.e. whether
the type of the target object is the same as it was last time), and then transfer control
directly to the target method - with no virtual tables involved at all. If the assertion fails, an attempt may be made to convert this to a megamorphic call site (i.e. with multiple possible types); if this also fails (or if it is the first call), a regular long-winded lookup is performed, using vtables (for virtual methods) and itables (for interfaces).

***Edit***: The [Hotspot Wiki](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/VirtualCalls) has more details on the vtable and itable stubs. In the polymorphic case, it still puts an inline cache version into the call site. However, the code actually is a stub that performs a lookup in a vtable, or an itable. There is one vtable stub for each vtable offset (0, 1, 2, ...). [Interface calls](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/InterfaceCalls) add a linear search over an array of itables before looking into the itable (if found) at the given offset.

Comment: Those Hotspot Wiki pages on VirtualCalls and InterfaceCalls seem to be what I'm looking for. Still have to get around to read all of it though.

Comment: The Wiki has been moved to https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/Home

Comment: The oracle wiki has been frozen, I think https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/Main is where the updateable information ended up.