# Can an interface be a superclass?

Tags: java

In the [Java documentaion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/predefined.html) it states:

> `@Override` annotation informs the compiler that the element is meant to override an element declared in a superclass.

I have a class that *implements* an *interface* and the implemented method statements have the `@Override` annotation.
Does this mean (according to the docs) that the interface is a superclass of my class? But how can it be, considering that interfaces only contain 'empty' methods, not methods that actually do stuff?

My code is LibGDX-related:

```
public class MouseAndKeyboard implements ApplicationListener {
    private Texture plane1;
    private Sprite mainPlane;
    private SpriteBatch mainSpritePacket;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

        ...
```

Comment: An Interface can only be extended by an Interface, but can only be implemented by either an Abstract class or a Concrete class

Comment: related : [How are java interfaces implemented internally? (vtables?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423968/how-are-java-interfaces-implemented-internally-vtables)

Comment: Interfaces were created so that multi-inheritence is "possible" (with big limitations). So basically it could be considered a Superclass. You also have to look at it from the other way around: An abstract superclass can also have an abstract method with no methodbody at all!

Comment: Tutorials are *descriptive* documentation; Javadoc is *normative*. When in doubt, you must always check the normative documentation.

Comment: Using @Override was not legal on inherited interface methods until Java 6. That section of the web page might be old text that has not been updated.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik actually he DID look into the "normative" documentation which contained the sloppy definition which is in question.

Comment: @DHall is the first one to give a plausible explanation as to why the definition might be false...

Comment: @ITroubs: It *could* be considered that, but it isn't.  An interface is a super-*type*, not a super-*class*.

Comment: @ITroubs How do you know that when the link points to the tutorial page.? Furthermore, DHall is wrong on the version: the change did not happen until Java 7.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik oh my mistake. You are right. Looking into the doc it states supertype for the `@Override` annotation.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik no it was java 6. if you're going to call me out at least check your facts

Comment: @DHall [That is precisely what I did](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html). What is your source of facts?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I just doubled-checked with IBM JDK 6 and `@Override` is supported there for interfaces. I'm pretty sure this is also the case for Oracle JDK 6, though I don't have the documentaton at hand. Sadly, the Javadoc of JDK 6 still mentions "superclass" not "supertype".

Comment: @Puce Well, this question is precisely about the difference between normative and descriptive :) `javac` may have *informally* allowed that, but it was non-compliant with the specification in that respect. Java 6 as a specification did not allow it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For questions like this it's best to check the Javadoc. And the Javadoc mentions "supertype" not "superclass": https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html

Comment: Right! Good spot. I don't know what the definition of supertype is now though :(

Comment: Either an extended class or an implemented interface.

Comment: @Gimby I don't know the definite specification, but e.g. an extended interface is also a supertype (e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html)

Answer (score 1):

It's still called an interface, it prevents you from making mistakes, so you should use it however.

Checkout the JSR http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/#9.6.4.4

**Chapter 9.6.4.4 @Override**

also:

[Should we @Override an interface's method implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212614/should-we-override-an-interfaces-method-implementation)

Answer (score 1):

`@Override` always bothered me also, because it is used for both overriding the actual superclass method, and implementing an interface method. So, the documentation in taht part isn't written in the best way.

> considering that interfaces only contain 'empty' methods

This isn't true anymore, in Java 8 interfaces can contain default implementations for declared methods.

Comment: It hasn't "always" been that way; `@Override` was originally introduced in Java 5 with semantics strictly applying to overrides. In Java 7 this was extended to implementations because that way the annotation became much more useful. Its misleading name stays with us, unfortunately.

Comment: Asuming interfaces are used to provide the means of multi-inheritence in Java, then @Override is not misleading at all

Comment: @ITroubs Common sense and the Java Language Specification agree that "override" does not apply to implementing interface methods. Common sense and the JLS diverge, however, when it comes to abstract methods defined by a class: these are "overridden" as far as the JLS is concerned.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yes, my use of `always` wasn't the best, just referring to the fact that this inclarity has been around for a while.

Comment: @ITroubs `multi-inheritance` via interfaces is also misleading imho

Answer (score 0):

The explaination in the documentation is a bit sloppy. An Interface is not a superclass because a class can only have one superclass but implement multiple Interfaces. But you should still use the `@Override` Annotation for interface methods to show that this method ins inherited (there is no different Annonation only for interface methods).

Comment: Looking at it from a purely OO perspective an interface is the fake version of multi inheritence