# Design reasons behind making ToUpper a static method on Char

Tags: c#

In C#, we have this non-static method on the type string:

```
"abc".ToUpper()
```

but for char, we need to use a static method:

```
char.ToUpper('a')
```

When introducing c# to beginners, they always expect to be able to write the following:

```
'a'.ToUpper()
```

Does anyone have insights as why it was designed like this?

The only thing I can think of is performance but then I would have expected a static ToUpper() for the type string too.

Comment: My suspicion is that it's simply that whoever designed the one method didn't work with whoever created the other.

Comment: @Khanh TO: char is a value type and can't be null unless it's a Nullable<char>, which this question is *not* about. And strings *can* be null, yet string.ToUpper() is an instance method and ToUpper() on a null string results in an exception, so...

Comment: Objection - call for speculation :)

Comment: Char is a value type and therefore immutable, such a method cannot work.  It could be written as a method that returns the upper-cased char, like String.ToUpper().  But you would have paid for a boxing conversion in .NET 1.x, the most obvious reason why it wasn't considered back then.  You can easily add it today with an extension method.

Comment: Well, actually Strings are immutable too.   Also,  there is no performance difference between a static call or an object member in this context (they are both immutable objects).

Comment: This is just speculation,  but I think the answer is a lot less interesting:   .Net 1.x was heavily based on Java, and in Java primitives are not Objects,  therefore for a 'char' value, you just don't have the option of calling a method,  as in  'a'.toUpperCase(),  so in Java they had from the beginning a static method style for primitives ( Character.toUpperCase('a')  )  and a member method for String, which is an Object  ( myStr.toUpperCase() ).    My guess is,  C# just followed the same convention.

Comment: @HansPassant Strictly speaking value types could be mutable, but of course I totally agree such bad form would likely not be found in the BCL.  I'm not sure what you mean by *it could be written as a method that returns the upper-cased char* - that's actually exactly what it does, which is also why the mutability comment seems irrelevant. Finally I'm not sure where we have boxing here, or why anything would have change in that regard since .NET 1.x (as we don't have generics in this case).

Comment: @HansPassant strings are immutable too I'm not sure how that applies

Answer (score 2):

The difference lies in the fact that `string` is a [reference type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx), and `char` is a keyword that represents the .Net Framework's [Char Structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char(v=vs.110).aspx). When you call `Char.ToUpper('a')` you are actually using the Char Structure in C#. Structures are [Value Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch(v=VS.100).aspx). Value Types are immutable.

Since structs are immutable, methods that act upon the struct itself do not work as expected ([see Why are Mutable Structs Evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil)). Thus static methods are needed. When calling `Char.ToUpper(aChar)` you are not actually changing aChar, instead, you are creating a new instance of a character that is the uppercase representation of the character you passed in as a parameter and returning it. The example below demonstrates this.

```
Char aChar = 'a';
Char.ToUpper(aChar);
//aChar still equals 'a'

Char bChar = 'b';
bChar = Char.ToUpper(bChar);
//bChar now equals 'B'
```

The reason char has other methods that allow you to do things like `'a'.Equals('a');` is because value types and reference types both inherit from [Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object(v=vs.110).aspx), which defines those methods (technically, value types are of type `System.ValueType`, which inherits from `System.Object`). These methods do not enact any changes to the object itself.

## Edit - Why this question is actually speculation

As I'm very curious to see if there's an actual answer to "why do `char`s not have a `.ToUpper()` method", I decided to check out the [CSharp 5 Language Specification Document](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=7029), I have found the following:

`char` is an Integral Type (pg 80), which is a subset of Simple Types. Simple Types themselves are just predefined Struct Types. Struct types are Value Types that "can declare constants, fields, *methods*, properties, indexers, operators, instance constructors, static constructors, and nested types" (pg 79).

`string` is a Class Type, which is a Reference Type (pg 85). Class Types define "a data structure that contains data members (constants and fields), function members (*methods*, properties, events, indexers, operators, instance constructors, destructors and static constructors), and nested types" (pg 84).

At this point, it is obvious that `char`s can support a `.ToUpper()` method (which is why the extension method works). However, as the question states, they do not support one. **At this point I'm convinced any reasoning as to why this is true is pure speculation (unless you're on the C# team, of course).**

Comment: String are immutable too so I'm not sure why it matters here. It was never about expecting 'a'.ToUpper() to mutate the value type, just to return the uppercase value.

Comment: @FrancoisBeaussier Good point. I ended up looking into the specifications of C# 5, which made me reach the same conclusion as sara (from the comment section of your question). See my edit for further explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Hans Passant mentioned that it is possible to achieve this syntax easily via extension methods.  I'll provide the code here in case anyone is deeply attached to using that syntax.

```
public static class MyExtensionMethods
{
    public static char ToUpper( this char c )
    {
        return char.ToUpper( c );
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
'a'.ToUpper()
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question that was asked. The question wants to know *why* not *here is how you do it*

Answer (score 1):

(sorry, not enough space in a comment -- I know this isn't a complete answer.)

This seems to be a pattern across all the primitive types; `int`, `double`, and `bool`, for example, also do not have methods (except `ToString()` variants). So it's not just `char` -- it's a property of all the primitive types that c# defines.

I would guess (and it is a guess) that any time you access data, you're either directly accessing bits of RAM -- the primitive values like `int` and `char` and `byte` -- or you're accessing a .NET construct like an object or struct. A char is always 2 bytes at a particular memory address. So the framework can treat it like a raw memory location.

If we try to treat the raw RAM as objects, you'll either have to 'box' everything to do any work, or it's just not possible. My guess is that you can't do some core feature like [virtual method dispatch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9808982/6722) on primitives, and that the world of objects and the world of primitives has to be kept separate.

Anyway, hope that advances the conversation on some level...