# How should I do in a project which is Firebase is mandatory but there isn't any Firebase?

Tags: flutter, firebase

My friend and I are doing a project. He will do the Firebase part and I will do the Front-End part.There is a problem:
**There isn't any Firebase**.So I don't have any data.
In that case what should I do?

Should I create fake datas or an Class with parameters like that:?

````
class Firebase_Datas{
   String name;
   String surname;
   .
   ..
   ...
   if (name == null){
    return "---";  //I assumed that arguments were given.
   .
   ..
   ...
}
}
```
````

Comment: What do you mean by "There isn't any Firebase"? You can set up a Firebase project in a matter of minutes (if not seconds...). Even if it is not the final/real project your front-end code will stay valid as soon as there is no DB data model changes or Storage bucket/"folders" naming. You just have to adapt the Firebase config to point to another project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speaking in general, you should do [Interface-Oriented Programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848442/what-exactly-is-interface-based-programming) at some level, which means: talk to your partner and align what each side expects.

But your question specifically asks about models. There's no correct answer, but what I would suggest you to do is:

- create the model as in your example:

```
    class UserModel {
      final String name;
      final String surname;
    }
```

- use the repository pattern to shield your UI/Controller from changes in models

```
    abstract class UserRepository {
      Future<UserModel> getUser();
    }
    class UserFakeRepository implements UserRepository {
      @override
      Future<UserModel> getUser() {
        final result = UserModel('John', 'Doe');
      }
    }
```

- in your UI/Controller layer you should use the repository instead of feeding the UI directly with the data:

```
    class _UserPageState extends State<UserPage> {
      UserModel? user;
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        _repository.getUser().then((result) =>
        setState(() {
          user = result;
        }));
      }
    }
```

- after the Firebase part is built, you can implement a new UserRepository and change your dependency injection (meaning, stop using UserFakeRepository and use this new one):

```
    class UserFirebaseRepository implements UserRepository {
      @override
      Future<UserModel> getUser() {
        final result = _firebase.query(...);
      }
    }
```

- for unit testing purposes, I advise you to create a wrapper for Firebase.instance. If you use them directly in your repositories, you'll be unable to write unit tests for your repositories.
- by writing code this way, your UI layer will remain unchanged when you integrate the app with Firebase.